# c # write one line of code from list to array

Tags: c#, string, arraylist

Is it possible in C# to combine the `Name` properties of the `List<Tag>` object with a comma  `","` with a line command?
`"World,Tech,Science,Arts"`

```cs
public class Tag
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
List<string> tagNames;
foreach (var tag in tags)
{
   tagNames.add(tag.Name);
}
string result = String.Join(",", tagNames);
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
string result = String.Join(",", tags.ForEach(t => t.Name));
```

Comment: You should use `Select`, not `ForEach` and make sure you have `using System.Linq;`

Comment: `List`'s `ForEach` has done more damage for people's understanding of LINQ, than good for C# as a whole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ForEach` runs a block of code. You're looking for [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0) that projects each element in a different form:

```cs
string result = String.Join(",", tags.Select(t => t.Name));
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible in C# to combine the Name properties of the List
> object with a comma "," with a line command?

Another one-liner using [Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-5.0) instead of `String.Join()`:

```
string result = tags.Select(t => t.Name).Aggregate((a, b) => (a + "," + b));
```